# Get Manager step does not work in MS Flow when using approval flow with Sharepoint Online calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure-ad, ms-flow

I'm trying to setup a Flow that works with Sharepoint online vacation calendar.

I was wondering if any of you guys can hint me in the right direction as MS Flow dev. forums are inconsistently active and sometimes I have to wait quite a while to get an answer.

So my deal is this - I have a flow setup, and by the logic in it. it should work fine, but there is a step called "Get manager" and it fails to get the sid from Azure AD manager field (this field is not empty in my Azure AD).

My flow looks like this:
[image]

I tried this command in Powershell with the latest Azure module installed:

```
Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName <expected email of the manager>
```

and it did not return the email of any user I tried with. So I'm suspect there maybe something missing the Azure AD settings, but I'm not sure entirely.